# define function with 3d discrete points and find corresponding value from that function

Tags: interpolation

Now I have a set of 3d discrete points in the form of {x,y,z} and want to interpolate them and define them into a function making x and y as the variables. Subsequently read corresponding values of z with x and y values which don´t exist in my data set. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

[Interpolation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Interpolation.html).  If

```
list = {x1, y1, z1}, {x2, y2, z2}, .....}
```

then

```
func = Interpolation[ list ];
```

will give an interpolating function.  Then you can get values by entering `func[x, y]` you will get the corresponding `z`.  If these values are far outside the range of the input values, then the result will not be so reliable.